# How to create a 3D convolutional neural network using mxnet?

Tags: python-2.7, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, mxnet

I have a folder containing files with 11*11*21 3D data and I am trying to do a binary classification with a 3D convolutional neural network. I only found the tutorial for the 2D convolutional NN on the gluon tutorials and I am not sure what things to change to accommodate 3D data. I am following this tutorial but using my own data, I tried to change the layer to 3D but I am stuck on what else I need to change. https://gluon.mxnet.io/chapter04_convolutional-neural-networks/cnn-gluon.html

I am very new to convnets and 3D convnets so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

For something as simple as the example tutorial you provided, you simply need to change `Conv2D` to `Conv3D` and `MaxPool2D` to `MaxPool3D` and your data would have to be in `(N, C, D, H, W)` layout instead of `(N, C, H, W)` layout.

Comment: Thanks very much for the help. I simply uploaded my 3D data into a mxnet dataset and used a dataloader to get batches and fed that to the neural network. Therefore, the input is only (N, C, H, W), how do I make it so that it is (N,C, D, H, W) as you described? Sorry for the stupid questions.

Comment: What are the three dimensions of your data? Doesn't it have width, heigh, and depth?